# Drawn text highlighting. Core text? Something other?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I want to draw highlighted parts of text, but I haven't any ideas, how can I do it.

Result, which I want:
[image]

[image]

Caption on image is one attributed string, where I'm finding hashtags and drawing it in blue color. Nickname in header - one simple NSString. I want to show rects, and text, which user wants to find. Have you any ideas, how I can find CGRects for NSRanges in my drawn string?

PS: I want to detect coordinate of last character for other image works.